# DOMDocument::schemaValidate() exceeds the allowed maximum length of '255'

Tags: php

I used DOMDocument in PHP5 to construct an XML message. After it has been constructed, I call schemaValidate() method against the message, and then run into following error:

PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element 'message': [facet 'maxLength'] The value has a length of '353'; this exceeds the allowed maximum length of '255'.

Is there anyone who ever run into similar question? How to enlarge the maximum length?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value defined in your schema?

Answer (score 2):

> How to enlarge the maximum length?

Change the schema.

Comment: It's not the schema overlength, it's the message.